# Do all Linux processes write EOF to stdout when they are terminating/have finished terminating?

Tags: linux, process, python, lxc, output

I'm having trouble with sending `shutdown -h 0` to a `lxc` Debian container (i.e. executing this command in the lxc) with with the python `pexpect` module (in a python script). In this module the user can "expect" (= wait for process output) a certain substring, amongst others EOF, which leads me to the question in order to be able to debug further why EOF isn't recognized in the output. I need to know what I can "expect" after termination of the process in order to wait for the process to end. I can't simply wait for the process because the `pexpect` module hides non-blocking functions for that.

The `pexpect` module (see http://www.bx.psu.edu/~nate/pexpect/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect for details) wraps the reception of EOF in the read system call in a (duck)type and makes it usable in `pexpect.expect` (an encapsulation of possible output/feedback of a process).

I've been wondering that because some processes like `ls` are expected to terminate with EOF, i.e. the `pexpect` sense of EOF (example at http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).

Comment: I'm not sure about the `expect` part of your question, but in Unix, EOF is not something that you can write to stdout.  It's not a character or byte sequence.  When a process is reading bytes out of a file, it eventually will reach the end of that file, and the `read` syscall will return a special value to indicate that there's nothing more to read.  This is an EOF condition.  In the case of a pipeline, a writer process could close a file descriptor (using, eg, `fclose(stdout)`), and the reader would see that when calling `read` on stdin.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly you're trying to do?  If you were just trying to use python to execute `shutdown -h now` you'd be using the subprocess module, not pexpect - so what are you trying to get expect to do for you?

Comment: What process are you waiting to finish?  If you're waiting for a `shutdown -h now` command to finish, you'll never see it - because the machine shuts down before the command finishes.

Comment: No I'm waiting for `shutdown -h 0` executed in the Linux container `lxc` which causes the container to the shut down but not the machine it is running on!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOF indicates that no further input is to be expected on a resource which possibly provides an endless amount of data (e.g. a stream). This situation is often expressed by writing a single character on the stream (to be defined by the underlying system (likely a OS or runtime environment )).

As processes use streams for inter-process communication they need to indicate the limits of their output and sending processes need to inidicate the limits of their input using EOF. The underlying system will very certainly forward this input and output to its own process handling mechanisms making EOF avaialble for evaluation in the program/on the system.

Note about `pexpect` use case in the question: `shutil.pexpect` doesn't seem to be suitable to copy files of a `lxc` container. It got stuck and the time offset of the `pexpect` output causes the confusion.

Comment: This answer is fundamentally incorrect.  EOF is not a character that is written to a stream.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then running this `shutdown -h 0` command I'd suggest running `halt` instead, or running this command from the host, `lxc-shutdown -n <name>`.

*Source: [9.5 Monitoring and Shutting Down Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_shutdown_containers.html)*

Comment: Thanks for your support on `pexpect`, it helped my, but didn't answer the question. I experienced no difference between `halt` and `shutdown -h` so far. As everything is working out after fixing the issue described in my answer, I didn't test `lxc-shutdown -n`.