# Is there a process which doesn't send EOF before terminating and how to create it?

Tags: linux, process, stdout, stderr

I suspect a process not to send EOF when killed with `SIGINT` and `SIGKILL` respectively. Can that be the case (or do all processes always send EOF to `stdout` and `stderr` after being terminated with whatever signal)? If yes, how can I immitate such a process so that I can use it in a Java unit test (which needs to run on Linux only for starters)?

The english [Wikipedia EOF article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) isn't clear about that, the [german](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_file) says that EOF "may" be sent.

I'm aware of the fact this is probably an XY problem and asking for support in debugging the Java code would get things fixes more quickly, but I'm interested in a getting an answer to this question as well. I'm also aware that process handling has been improved in Java 9 which I can't use yet.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 with Linux 4.10.

Comment: No process sends anything after `SIGKILL`.

Comment: That explains a lot. That answers the question, doesn't it?

Comment: That would answer the question only if there were no other signals.

Comment: AFAIK, EOF isn't something that is sent, it's the state of an input stream.

Comment: The incorrect premise that processes "send EOF" can be traced back to the questioner's incorrectly answered question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139534/5132 back in 2014.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `EOF` isn't really "sent". It's an event where your process calls the `read` system call and it returns `0`, which for pipes happens when the other end of the pipe has been closed (by all processes that have it, if the filedescriptor has been duplicated).

The kernel will always close *all* filedescriptors in terminating processes.
There's no way around it (even filedescriptors of SIGKILL'ed processes get closed). If any of those filedescriptors is a last reference to a pipe filedescriptor write end, the next`read` on the corresponding read end will return 0, which `stdio` will interpret as an `EOF`.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably not a problem if several `EOF` characters are sent. Thus you can run your Java program together with shell code that outputs `EOF` after the Java program has exited.

```
( javaprog ; echo -n $'\4' ) | program_waiting_for_eof
```

Some configuration for the signal handling is necessary, though, to ensure that the Java process is killed but the followong code still executed. If this is a suitable approach for you (which you may test by killing the Java process directly with `kill $PID` from another terminal) then I can provide additional information hwo to do that if you need it.

Comment: The process I suspect to not send EOF isn't necessarily a Java program/program interpreted by `java`, but can be any process I control from within a Java program. The program in question is PostgreSQL's server binary `postgres`.

Comment: @KarlRichter That does not make a difference in this case.

Comment: @HaukeLaging EOT (ASCII character 4) is not EOF (lack of any character)